# Required output is 66.6 but I am getting gibberish (as posted below), how to fix this?

Tags: c++, inheritance, return

To calculate total in void display, I need the values of part1marks, part2marks and score. Hence I have created return functions (This is how I have to do it as per my assignment). However, I am getting undesirable output as shown below.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class student
{
    int rollno;
public:
    void getnumber()
    {
        cout << "Enter roll number: ";
        cin >> rollno;
        cout << endl;
    }
    int putnumber()
    {
        return rollno;
    }
};
class test : virtual public student
{
    float part1marks;
    float part2marks;
public:
    void getmarks()
    {
        cout << "Enter Marks(Parts 1 and 2): ";
        cin >> part1marks >> part2marks;
        cout << endl;
    }
    float putmarks()
    {
        float marks = part1marks + part2marks;
        return marks;
    }
};
class sports : virtual public student
{
    float score;
public:
    void getscore()
    {
        cout << "Enter score: ";
        cin >> score;
        cout << endl;
    }
    float putscore()
    {
        return score;
    }
 };
class result : public test, public sports
{
    float total;
public:
    void display()
    {
        test t;
        sports s;
        float sc = s.putscore();
        float ms = t.putmarks();
        total = sc + ms;
        cout <<"Total marks= "<< total;
    }

};
int main()
{
    result obj;
    obj.getnumber();
    obj.getmarks();
    obj.getscore();
    obj.display();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Expected Output

Enter roll number: 21

Enter Marks(Parts 1 and 2): 22.2
22.2

Enter score: 22.2

Total marks= 66.6 Press any key to continue . . .

Actual Output

Enter roll number: 21

Enter Marks(Parts 1 and 2): 22.2
22.2

Enter score: 22.2

Total marks= -3.22123e+08Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: @NathanOliver can I do that somehow in Visual Studio?

Comment: Sure.  Set a breakpoint on the first line in `main` and then press either the green arrow "Local Windows Debugger" or press F5

Comment: Visual studio has one of the best debuggers out there. [Start reading somewhere around here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019)

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/5910058) - *Please* read [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25385174/5910058).

Comment: Look at your code line by line with your debugger and pay close attention to the data types you are using.

Comment: `int putnumber()
        {
            return rollno;
        }` - How quaint. A getter named `put`foo.. which even returns a variable not initialized in-class, nor by the constructor, so very easily an uninitialized variable (the reading of which is Undefined Behaviour)..

Comment: `class test : virtual public student` - why `virtual` inheritance? *Why*?  Virtual inheritance should be used *extremely* sparingly, and only when there is a *very* good reason. Definitely "expert only" territory...

Comment: `system("pause");` - *Not* portable.

Comment: `using namespace std;` - *Usually* a bad idea.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Whoops. Right you are. So there is. But still, why is that? For something like this it looks over complicated for no real reason.

Comment: `void getscore()` - I would expect a function named `getscore` to `return` me a score that I could then print or do calculations on or whatever. That that function returns `void` and has the side effect of *printing* the score is surprising (and looks like bad design to me).

Comment: @JesperJuhl most of these are limitations put on by my teacher. I have to use virtual class. I have to use namespace std. I got the problem by debugging, in putscore and putmarks, the values for part1marks, part2marks and score are not the user inputted values, but rather default weird values. So how can I make it so that in putscore and putmarks, input values( the ones taken in getscore and getmarks) are returned?

Comment: Sounds like a poor teacher *to me*, if that's where this design came from.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I think it's pointless to do code review for school assignments. People are not gonna learn proper coding style unless they start working on real projects and see for themselves how bad is bad code. We repeat under every single question that `using namespace std` is bad, but it's school that teaches it, so it's school that gives the rules. I guess for school assignment it's more important to show some concept, rather than anything else - if you know the concept, you can reapply it with good code or bad code, doesn't matter.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen It's late and I'm bored, so I'm just commenting on random questions (hopefully still sensibly). If this was an *actual* code review at work, I'd have a lot more to say about this code..

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code yet? Check `display()` and the values of `t` and `s` when you use them.

Comment: "maybe help me" - I think the comments that have been made about your code and the links to tools you should investigate, *very much counts as* help.. Don't expect anyone to debug the code for you and just post a solution. You are the one who has to do that work.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I did, and I saw the values not being the user inputted values. I still cant figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Can you find any place where the values inputted by user are present? How could you retrieve them?

Comment: should cin>>score store a value in score which should be returned in putscore? I have no clue...

Comment: Well, morotspaj already gave you the answer.

Comment: @SohamRay *NathanOliver can I do that somehow in Visual Studio?* -- Seriously, there is a big "Debug" menu on the main task bar in Visual Studio.  I am surprised you weren't curious as to what that menu item did.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197314/discussion-on-question-by-soham-ray-required-output-is-66-6-but-i-am-getting-gib).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating new objects with uninitialized values in `display()`.

```cpp
    void display()
    {
        test t;   // <- This is a new object with uninitialized members variables
        sports s; // <- This is a new object with uninitialized members variables
        float sc = s.putscore(); // Replace with this->putscore() or simply putscore()
        float ms = t.putmarks(); // Replace with this->putmarks() or simply putmarks()
        total = sc + ms;
        cout <<"Total marks= "<< total;
    }
```

Multiple inheritance is almost never a good idea. Is your assignment really forcing you to do that?

Comment: sadly, yes :( and I have to submit a whole compilation of different programs tomorrow...

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked, I can rest easy now xD.